# Add UISlider on UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I want to add a `UISlider` on a `UIAlerView` but I am not able to do that. I also google that but I found only two answers and both of them are not showing any any result here is code what I found and applied in my project:

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"msg" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"ok", nil];
alertView.title =  @"title";

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(alertView.frame.origin.x+10,alertView.frame.origin.y+20,100, 100.0);
UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[slider setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
slider.minimumValue = 0.0;
slider.maximumValue = 10.0;
slider.continuous = YES;
slider.value = 25.0;
[alertView addSubview:slider];
[alertView show];
```

I think the frame of slider is not proper thats why its not being displayed.
can anyone help me in that.....
Thank you in advance...

Comment: Since iOS7 you can't add `UIView` to a `UIAlertView`. You have to do (or use an existent found in GitHub/CocoaControls/...) your own UIAlertView-like.

Answer (score 1):

**You are adding the Slider in Alert view not in parent view of Alert view**.

So your frame value will add the slider some where wide in alert view, result will be hidden on alert view.

so replace this line

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(alertView.frame.origin.x+10,alertView.frame.origin.y+20,100, 100.0);
```

To

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(10,20,100, 100.0);
```

The UIAlertView is also a UIView. I indeed, you could add the subview in it. But [Apple says](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html)

"**The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.**"

So Better to have custom view which will act as alertview.[Like this one](https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview)

Comment: thank u very much friend but still its not visible..:(